# Excel Formula for 2 words

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find specific text (in one column) and calculate it and display the answer in another column.

For instance,

1. find "allocated"
2. if the date less than today - display SMS2
3. Find"non-allocated"
4. if the date more than 7 days fom current date- display sms3

below is my current formula (its wrong) -

```
=IF(DM4="allocated",DP4<1,if(DM4="non-allocated, DP4>today()+6, "sms1","sms2")
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I think you misunderstand what this site is for; if you're a programmer and you have a ***specific*** question about a section of code that is giving you a problem, please [edit] your question with code/formula examples and details about what you've tried so far.  See the [tour] as well as [ask] and [mcve].  Beginner's tutorials are available online.  I'd suggest a search for "Excel nested if statements".

Comment: Blind guess: `=IF(AND(DM4="allocated",DP4<1),IF(AND(DM4="non-allocated", DP4>TODAY()+6), "sms1","sms2"),"zzz")`

Comment: @PetterFriberg - you may have noticed that I reversed both my down-vote and close-vote **prior** to your 'spanking' but subsequent to the op's edit. In fact, I would have also deleted my comment if it wasn't for your comment flag.

Comment: @Jeeped -- [chat?](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162877/bc4x4dataguy)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
=IF(AND(DM4="allocated",BP4<TODAY()),"sms2",IF(AND(DM4="non-allocated",BP4>TODAY()+7),"sms1","No value"))
```